# selectOneMenu does not show the proper value but getter gets it

Tags: java, jsf, enums

Given this selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{fb.aktionTxt}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.FBAEnum}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

this bean code

```
public FehlerBewertungAktionEnum[] getFBAEnum() {
        return FehlerBewertungAktionEnum.values();
}
```

this enum

```
public enum FehlerBewertungAktionEnum {

    NEKO_NEKO("NEK0-NEK0           "),
    CURSOR_PARAMETER("CURSOR-PARAMETER    "),
    CURSOR_LEER("CURSOR-LEER         ");

    private final String str;
    FehlerBewertungAktionEnum(String str) { this.str = str;}
    public String toString(){ return str; }

}
```

and a database value of aktionTxt

```
|CURSOR_LEER         | (20 chars)
```

why does it display NEK0-NEK0 (first element of the enum) instead of CURSOR_LEER in my selectOneMenu, when the getter returns `|CURSOR_LEER         |`? I debugged the jsf page and found that no `<option>` has the `selected` attribute.

The strange thing also is that I can create a new element with the same jsf code and it will properly save my new object to the DB. I am pretty sure there is no way to use `trim()` here since then I cannot save my `fb` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh - my - god

The database value is `|CURSOR_LEER         |`(20 chars) with an **underscore** while my enum uses a **hyphen**. How could neither me, my colleague or anybody reading this not see this for so long >.<

Comment: Bugs like this are hardest to spot, especially if there are several other more obvious suspects :)

Answer (score 1):

`NEK0-NEK0` is being selected because it is the first one in the list, and none of the items could be matched by value to `#{fb.aktionTxt}`. You could add one default item which will be selected in this case.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{fb.aktionTxt}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one..."/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.FBAEnum}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If `#{fb.aktionTxt}` resolves to (its type is) `FehlerBewertungAktionEnum`, it should work. But, if it is `String` then no value from the list would be equal to it because `Enum` is compared to `String`, resulting in the first item being selected. In this case, if `#{fb.aktionTxt}` is `String`, you could try this for `<f:selectItems>`

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.FBAEnum}" var="myEnum" itemLabel="#{myEnum.toString()}" itemValue="#{myEnum.toString()}"/>
```

Comment: default is not needed since the DB will only contain those valid "Strings". Your solutions seems reasonable to me but isn't working; same effect :( btw, aktionTxt is a java.lang.String

Comment: @dasLort Could you set this as label, just to check that values are passed OK `itemLabel="#{myEnum.toString()} == #{fb.aktionTxt}"`? Also, check client and server logs to see if there is somthing relevant

Comment: sorry for not responding, was ill. When I add a `Q` at the end of the label, the output will be `NEK0-NEK0 == CURSOR_LEER Q`. I think, there is some automatic trim going on here

Comment: for some unknown reason a once working ear is not working anymore and I had to switch to your approach. Server didn't change, ear didn't change. We have no idea what happened

Comment: Values in the database changed?